# AJAX function to POST 4 variables

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, post, variables

Ive been having great frustration for hours now trying to remember my AJAX!

Im trying to write a function which will be called that will simply POST 4 variables to a given URL, written in javascript and not jquery such as:

```
function postVariables(URL, var1, var2, var3, var4)
{
  ......
  return true;
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: I've never done it witout library help, so just commenting rather than answering; here's an example: http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax_xmlhttp_using_post.php

Comment: the easiest and comprensive ajax tut http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_examples.asp

Answer (score 0):

Been a while since I've done this without jQuery but something like

```
function postVariables(URL, var1, var2, var3, var4)
{
  var xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();

  var postvars = "var1=" + var1 + "&var2=" + var2 etc;
  xhr.open("POST", URL, true);

  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/html;");
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-length", postvars.length);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

  xhr.send(postvars);
}
```

I'm sure my syntax is off somewhere or other, but you should be able to search for XmlHttpRequest and find some valid samples.

ref: http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/